# Removing Comments with ASM

Tags: java, obfuscation

[ASM -> Java]
I want to know how to remove all comments and documentations from the classes with the ASM library in Java.
I'm asking here, because i dont found anything on google.
Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: ASM operates on bytecode, not on sourcecode. There are no comments and documentation in bytecode.